# How to override grouped.phtml file in my own module in magento 1.9.1.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, overrides, grouped-products, phtml

I want to overwrite grouped.phtml file located at

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\
```

path in my own module. My magento version is 1.9.1.0.

Please guide me.

Comment: are you  want override only grouped.phtml?

Comment: yes, Amit. Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Create New Layout file at Custom Module:

You can do this `layout`.First need to create `a frontend layout file customgrouped.xml` from this custom module like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <!-- start of routers 
    -->
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <custommodule>
                    <file>customgrouped.xml</file>
                </custommodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

### Change template file at new layout file

then on `customgrouped.xml` file using `grouped.phtml` name and using setTemplate function set template .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<!--
PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped for only grouped product view page
-->
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped> <!--  grouped.phtml  block name define at catalog.xml -->
        <reference name="product.info.grouped">
              <action method="setTemplate"><template>youpath/customgrouped.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped></layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I tried this one earlier. Unfortunately it is not working for me.

Comment: can you please show the grouped.phtml file layout code

Comment: <catalog_product_view>

     <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped> <!--  grouped.phtml  block name define at catalog.xml -->

        <reference name="product.info.grouped">

              <action method="setTemplate"><template>modulename/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml</template></action>

        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</catalog_product_view>

Comment: no no...  default layout code of grouped.phtml which was defined in your system

Comment: I have updated my comment. Please check it.

Comment: Sorry,,you did not got my point,I want the layout code of grouped.phtml before overwrite grouped.phtml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22619/discussion-between-milople-inc-and-amit-bera).

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. I found it. Actually it was issue with the code of view.phtml file I have overridden.

Comment: i am in chat....

Answer (score 1):

you can do this easily by `local.xml` file. What we are going to do here is, setting another template for the block which uses `grouped.phtml`. This particular template is only used for grouped products. So here I assume you want to use `custom/product/type/grouped.phtml` file instead of default `catalog/product/type/grouped.phtml`.

File : `app\design\frentend\rwd\default\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
        <reference name="product.info.grouped"> 
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>custom/product/type/grouped.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
</layout>
```

Now make sure you have defined the new phtml file at `app\design\frentend\rwd\default\custom/product/type/grouped.phtml`

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. I have already tried this. I want to use "\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\my module\catalog\product\view\type\grouped.phtml" file instead of "\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\grouped.phtml". Please check whether I am doing any mistake.

Comment: show your module  activation file and config.xml file. Put them along with the question and ping me